# A question regarding $\arctan x$

Tags: real-analysis

Well, I'm sorry if it is asked but I couldn't find anything similar what I'm struggling about.

$$\arctan x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

whenever $|x| < 1$

But in normal we also know that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$ while $|x| = 1$ is convergent by the alternating series test. (Also it equals to $\frac{\pi}{4}$)

I want to say that $\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ while $|x| ≤ 1$ But something makes me uncomfortable. Normally, at Taylor series we need to show that error function tends to $0$ while $n$ tends to infinity. But this series is not in form of derivatives of $\arctan(x)$ in other words it is not a Taylor series. So, do we need an extra step to say that whenever $|x| \le 1$ this series equal to the $\arctan(x)$ or we can just say that since the series is convergent we could conclude that it is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series is the antiderivative of the Taylor series for $\dfrac 1{1+x^2}$, and 
$$\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2},$$
that's why we can conclude that it converges to $\arctan x$ for $|x|\le 1$

Comment: Is it about the continuity of the functions? 
f'(x) is continuous on (-1,1) and f(x) is continuous on [-1,1].

Comment: $f'(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbf R$. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I meant f'(x) = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}$ is defined at whenever |x| < 1 since it diverges and we are not working on extended real number set.
Accordingly , f(x) is defined at whenever |x| ≤ 1. (assuming C = 0)

Comment: You mean that the sum of the series is  the restriction of $\arctan x$ to the interval $[-1,1]$? Yes, that is true. For other values of $s$, $\arctan x$ is the sum of other power series.